# Windows 7 and Excel 2013

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a formula subtracting dates that can answer 0, 1, 2, or over 2.

My problem is that I can not get a zero result to be identified as a result and not just a blank cell. I don't know what to do to get system to count a zero result.

This is my formula:

```
=IF($J5=1,"24",IF($J5=2,"48",IF($J5>=3,"over 48")))
```

How can I get a zero value result show as "24?"

Comment: Change `=1` to `<=1`

Comment: Hello.  I tried that in the past: =IF($J2-$B2<1,"24",IF($J2-$B2=1,"24",IF($J2-$B2=2,"48",IF($J2-$B2>2,"over 48")))). This causes every cell to turn to 24(previously false) even if formula ($J2-$B2) has not yet occurred.

Comment: Could you post some sample data,  so we could better understand your issue?

Comment: This is what I am trying to do: $j5 is the result from the formula H3-E3 (both of these are dates). I want to translate the result (1,2,3,..) to the hours (24, 48, >48). Rarely H3 and E3 can be the same date, which is where the zero problem occurs. Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

From you comments I assume that the cell containing the difference formula may contain integer values >=0 or it may be empty. If this is the case surround your formula with

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK($J5),$J5=0),24,YOUR_FORMULA)
```

Replace `"NO RESULT"` with whatever you want to appear in case of an empty cell.

Instead of using a case construct to translate calendar days to hours you can use a simple formula (for positive values in $J5):

```
=MAX($J5,1)*24
```

This will produce "24" for integer numbers <=1 but will not work for a blank input cell, but for a 0 input cell. If you combine it with the above `ISBLANK()` solution

```
=IF(ISBLANK($J5);24;MAX($J5,1)*24)
```

it will produce what you need.

Comment: Hi George.  I tried your solution and rec'd #NAME? with  "ISEMPTY".  I changed the  "ISEMPTY" to "ISBLANK"  then got 24 in all cells. This is what I am trying to do: $j5 is the result from the formula H3-E3 (both of these are dates).  I want to translate the result (1,2,3,..) to the hours (24, 48, >48). Rarely H3 and E3 can be the same date, which is where the zero problem occurs.  Hope this helps.

Comment: In this case you don't need a case construct with IFs but a simple formula will do the job. Just look in the edited solution.

Comment: hi George. Me again.  I tried the formula you suggested =IF(ISBLANK($J5),"NO RESULT",YOUR_FORMULA) with it just producing "24" when cells with formula =H-E has not yet been accessed. I just want a way to translate a zero result of =H-E into "24".  Thanks for all your attention.

Comment: This is the case with the second formula I suggested. If you combine it with the isblank solution form above it will do the job.